# DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Range messing up Name adding $ instead of?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, runtime-error

Everytime I try and put names in the ranges it keeps adding a $ instead of a ! like I typed it.  Using office 365.  Running the code inside excel trying to get it to import into Access but I keep getting an error.

```vb
Sub ImportLine14()

    Dim accappl As Access.Application
    Dim strpathdb As String
    Dim strpathxls As String
    'Dim myrange As String, myrow1 As String, myrow2 As String
    'Dim fullRange As Range

    strpathdb = "\\US5MS0005\_Group Folders\Public\Production Data\Production Database\dbPlantData_be.accdb"
    'path to the upload file
    
    strpathxls = "\\US5MS0005\_Group Folders\Public\Production Schedule SAP\Production Schedule 2022  DugTest.xlsm"
    
    Set accappl = New Access.Application
    
    accappl.OpenCurrentDatabase strpathdb
    Dim Page As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, LCol As Long
    Dim fullrange As String
    Dim PageName As String
    
    'fullrange = Worksheets("Line14P").Range(Worksheets("Line14P").Cells(1, 1), Worksheets("Line14P").Cells(lRow, LCol))
    
    PageName = Worksheets("Line14").Name
        
            lRow = Worksheets("Line14").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            LCol = Worksheets("Line14").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            fullrange = Worksheets("Line14").Range(Worksheets("Line14").Cells(1, 1), _
                           Worksheets("Line14").Cells(lRow, LCol)).Address
            xclam = PageName & "!" & fullrange
    
    accappl.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acImport, _
             SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
             TableName:="tblProcessOrder", Filename:=strpathxls, _
             HasFieldNames:=True, Range:=PageName & "!" & fullrange
    accappl.Quit
    
End Sub
```

Results from Immediate Window Show Correct

> Print PageName

```
Line14
Print fullrange
$A$1:$G$18
print xclam
Line14!$A$1:$G$18
Print PageName
Line14
```

But this Error Shows Up[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8ZBN.png) Not sure what Else to do

Comment: Similar Q where poster ended up naming the range and then using the name in `TransferSpreadsheet`: https://forum.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/17157-transferspreadsheet-range-until-eof/

Comment: My company firewall says that it has Malware so it won't allow me to look thank you tho.

Comment: The poster at the link I posted ended up naming the range `rngobj.Name = "MyRange"` and then using that name in the call to TransferSpreadsheet:   `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel97, "New table", "c:\test.xls", False, "MyRange"`

Comment: Thank you Tim, that is what I tried to do, however for some reason it doesn't like the $ signs in the range, I typed it in manually and did not work as well.  So after finding the last row I need to remove the $ from range.

Answer (score 0):

If data with headers starts at `A1`, you don't need cell ranges. So simply set up `Range` argument as `Line14!`.

But if do set up cell ranges, you do not need `$`. So simply set up `Range` as `Line14!A1:G18`.

Comment: Problem is, is that the range may change from each day depending on what is scheduled.

Comment: So then dynamically build the range as needed without `$` symbols. Did that not work?

Comment: Thank to those that tried to help, I instead used ADO in excel to export data into Access instead of calling access to do it.  I tried the other way but it kept wanting to replace the exclamation mark with the dollar sign.  It was the only dollar sign in the Range.

Comment: Hmmm...I used your exact code and ran `Range:=Replace(PageName & "!" & fullrange, "$", "")` (to remove all `$`) with no issue.

Comment: Hmm wonder if I have something not turned on I will retry.